# CMake with PCH rebuild all project after adding/deleting .cpp files

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I'm using CMake for my big project and target_precompile_headers for generating .pch file.

Problem: each time then I add or delete .cpp file in target source list, every translation unit gets recompiled

To demonstrate issue I created very basic project with this structure:

[image]

CMakeLists.txt is very simple:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project(SuperBasicProject)
set(TARGET_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})

add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} main.cpp empty_cpp1.cpp)

target_include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_precompile_headers(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE my_pch.h)
```

Compiler output after running first time:

```
Scanning dependencies of target SuperBasicProject
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SuperBasicProject.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.pch
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SuperBasicProject.dir/empty_cpp1.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SuperBasicProject.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable SuperBasicProject
[100%] Built target SuperBasicProject
```

Then I'm adding another source file (empty_cpp2.cpp) to project by modifying add_executable line:

```
 add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} main.cpp empty_cpp1.cpp empty_cpp2.cpp)
```

And after that reload cmake and press build button.

Compiler output:

```
Scanning dependencies of target SuperBasicProject
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SuperBasicProject.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.pch
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SuperBasicProject.dir/empty_cpp2.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SuperBasicProject.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SuperBasicProject.dir/empty_cpp1.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable SuperBasicProject
[100%] Built target SuperBasicProject
```

Why every translation unit gets recompiled and how to fix this? Then target is a project with hude codebase this behavior is unacceptable. Maybe I'm using target_precompile_headers wrong, or maybe there is another way, which not gonna recompile everything. I would appreciate any help.